# Why does the name manager keep randomly appearing in Excel when I copy/paste with CMD-C/CMD-V?

Tags: macos, ms-office, copy-paste

[image: Stupid Name Manager I didn't ask for]

My setup
Mac - stuck on Monterey 12.7.3 due to hardware preventing upgrade
Office 365 subscription
Version 16.81 (24011420)